# How to upgrade EC2 Ubuntu OS from 14.04 -> 16.04 -> 18.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I got a task to upgrade OS version of ubuntu from 14.04 to possibly 18.04. After searching and googling, there was no specific answer or description why I should treat the EC2 instance as disposable.

Is there a reason why normal upgrade instead of new instance spinoff with volume attachment is better choice?

Thanks

Help with my issue, since the answers are very misleading sometimes

Comment: Better is subjective, but re-deploy of the workload onto a new instance with an upgraded OS is much more standard, especially in the cloud. This can be tricky when no one knows how the workload works, which is likely the case if you're starting from a OS version that has been end of life for years to another version that is already EOL.